# Vibrations at Absolute Zero

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature

Is matter still vibrating at absolute zero temperature?  If it isn't, wouldn't we then be able to know both its position and momentum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A system at absolute zero will still have nonzero uncertainty in position and momentum.

As an example, consider the simplest vibrating system, the one dimensional harmonic oscillator with (angular) frequency $\omega$ and mass $m$. In it's ground state (i.e. the lowest possible energy for the system) the position probability amplitude is a Gaussian ('bell curve'):
$$ \psi(x)\propto e^{\frac{-m \omega x^2}{2 \hbar}}$$. The finite extent of that curve reflects the position uncertainty: $\Delta x = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2 m \omega}}$. One can also show that in this state the momentum uncertainty is $\Delta p= \sqrt{\frac{ m \omega \hbar}{2}}$, and it is a minimal uncertainty state ($\Delta p \Delta x = \hbar/2$).

This example is easily generalized to 3D and is actually quite relevant since vibrating systems can often be approximated quite well by a simple harmonic oscillator, especially at low energies.

Comment: Are you able to say why they are still vibrating?

Comment: Not sure how to answer that. Are they "vibrating" if the system is in the lowest stationary state? I would say not, but it is perhaps a matter of terminology. The wavefunction has finite extent so that there is uncertainty in position/momentum, but it is not 'moving' in any observable sense.

Answer (score 1):

There will still be vibrations due to zero-point energy. So it's still impossible to know both its position and momentum.

Comment: Is there any state below this zero point where the vibrations stop?

Comment: No. That's why it's called zero-point.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking about this backwards.

*Because* of the uncertainty principle, zero-point energy exists.

*Because* of the existence of zero-point energy, it is impossible to cool any object all the way to absolute zero.

Comment: But how is the uncertainty principle applicable to atomic sized particles? I thought it only applies to subatomic particles.

Comment: @AmbicaGovind The uncertainty principle applies to everything, but its effects are smaller for larger objects. Its effects on single atoms and small molecules have been measured. Heat is a macroscopic property, but it _emerges_ (that's the official jargon) from molecule-scale phenomena that are affected by the uncertainty principle. One of the effects is what I said. If you want to know more about this, please ask a new question.